# Get position in list of items from another list in Python

Tags: python, list

What I would like to do is find the positions of the `female` within the `fileHeader` list and use those positions to append a `0` to the items in `myList` that match `female`.

```
female = ['1', '102', '107', '115']

fileHeader = ['#CHROM', 'POS', '1', '100', '101', '102', '103', '107', '108', '109', '110', 
'111', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '11N', '12', '120', '13', 
'14', '15', '16N', '17N', '18N', '19', '2', '21', '22', '23', '24', 
'26', '27', '28', '29', '3', '30', '31', '33', '34', '35', '37', '38', 
'39', '4', '40', '41', '45', '5', '50', '53', '54', '57', '58', '6', 
'67', '68', '7', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '77', '78', '79', '8', 
'80', '89', '9', '90', '99', 'F0GM', 'F1Father', 'F1Mother']

myList = ['HE669455_1', '293', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 
'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'T', 
'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 
'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'T', 
'N', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'K', 'T', 'T']
```

Positions:

```
[3,6,8,14]
```

Desired output:

```
['HE669455_1', '293', 'T0', 'T', 'T', 'N0', 'T', 'N0', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 
'T', 'T0', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'T', 
'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 
'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'T', 
'N', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'K', 'T', 'T']
```

My attempt at trying to get the positions:

```
for item in female:
    [fileHeader].index(item)
```

Comment: Could you show the `myList` after the appends?

Comment: Question is unclear. Show the desired output.

Comment: Does removing brackets, that is `fileHeader.index(item)` do it for you?

Comment: Probably better to have less input and more description of what the input is

Comment: Made an edit with the positions and desired output

Comment: `[fileHeader]` creates a new list with one item: `fileHeader`, this is surely not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[fileheader].index()` is trying to get the index of a *new* list with one element in it (fileheader).

You want to append to `myList`, not `fileHandler`:

```
for item in female:
    myList[fileHeader.index(item)] += '0'
```

I used `+= 0` because your current `myList` is filled with strings. If they're lists, it would be:

```
for item in female:
    myList[fileHeader.index(item)].append(0)
```

**Output:**

`['HE669455_1', '293', 'T0', 'T', 'T', 'N0', 'T', 'N0', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T0', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'T', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'K', 'T', 'T']`